# Proof of Continuous Mapping Theorem

Tags: probability-theory

A particular version of the Continuous Mapping Theorem (according to my knowledge, some authors uses use the same name for similar but not identical  statements) states the following: if $\{X_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence of random variables and $g$ is continuous function $g:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, then:

- $g(X_n) \overset{a.s.}{\rightarrow} g(X)$ if $X_n \overset{a.s.}{\rightarrow} X$
- $g(X_n) \overset{p}{\rightarrow} g(X)$ if $X_n \overset{p}{\rightarrow} X$
- $g(X_n) \overset{d}{\rightarrow} g(X)$ if $X_n \overset{d}{\rightarrow} X$

where $\overset{a.s.}{\rightarrow}$, $\overset{p}{\rightarrow}$ and $\overset{d}{\rightarrow}$ indicate respectively almost sure convergence, convergence in probability and convergence in distribution.

In all the manuals I have consulted authors provide ad-hoc proofs for every single statement of the theorem. What is not clear to me is the reason why they do not prove only the case for almost sure convergence and resort to the well-known implications among the various types of convergence to obtain the remaining statements. What am I missing?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the result for almost sure convergence and if you want to prove the result for weak convergence you will need Skorohod's Theorem which is deep. Isn't it better to prove it directly?.

Comment: Sorry, I did not get your point. Why cannot I directly rely on the chain of implications described below?
$ g(X_n) \overset{a.s.}{\rightarrow} g(X) \; \; \Rightarrow  \; \;  g(X_n) \overset{p}{\rightarrow}  g(X) \; \; \Rightarrow  \; \;  g(X_n) \overset{d}{\rightarrow} g(X)$

Comment: This only proves that $X_n \to X$ **a.s.** implies $g(X_n) \to g(X)$ in distribution . It does not prove that $X_n \to X$ **in distribution** implies $g(X_n) \to g(X)$ in distribution .

Comment: True, in fact we must prove $g(X_n) \overset{a.s.}{\rightarrow} g(X)$. But please correct me if I am wrong, $\{ Y_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ with $Y_n \overset{def}{=} g(X_n)$ is a sequence of random variables.

Comment: @zeroKnowl If $(X_n)$ is a sequence of random variables and $g$ is continuous then $(g(X_n))$ is a sequence of random variables.

Comment: Ok, so if we know that $Y_n \overset{a.s.}{\rightarrow} Y$ (i.e. we prove it) we can conclude that  $Y_n \overset{p}{\rightarrow} Y$ and $Y_n \overset{d}{\rightarrow} Y$ directly, because $Y_n \overset{a.s.}{\rightarrow} Y$ implies $Y_n \overset{p}{\rightarrow} Y$, which implies $Y_n \overset{d}{\rightarrow} Y$. Am I wrong?

Comment: @zeroKnowl Nothing wrong here. This is perfectly logical.

Comment: Ok perfect, so now the point is the following: instead of proving every single statement in the aforementioned theorem, if we just prove that $g(X_n) \overset{a.s.}{\rightarrow} g(X)$, can we conclude directly that also the remaining statements hold because of the chain of implications described above?

Comment: No. If you are only told that $X_n \to X$ in distribution and you are asked to prove that $g(X_n) \to g(X)$ in distribution you cannot do that by proving almost sure convergence because almost sure convergence simply may not be true.

Comment: Thanks, it is clear now. Thanks for your time!